# FileStream faster way to read and write big file

Tags: vb.net, file, filestream

I have a speed problem and memory efficiency, I'm reading the cutting the big chunk of bytes from the .bin files then writing it in another file, the problem is that to read the file i need to create a huge byte array for it:

```
Dim data3(endOFfile) As Byte ' end of file is here around 270mb size
      Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
        fs.Seek(startOFfile, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        fs.Read(data3, 0, endOFfile)
    End Using
    Using vFs As New FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\test.bin", FileMode.Create) 'save
        vFs.Write(data3, 0, endOFfile)
    End Using
```

so it takes a long time to procedure, what's the more efficient way to do it?
Can I somehow read and write in the same file stream without using a bytes array?

Comment: Open both streams at once, stream the data by reading in a small amount (the default MS' `CopyTo` method uses is 81920 bytes), and writing it to the new file. Repeat until done.

Comment: @Llama thanks, can i have an answer, so can i choose it as correct

Comment: I'm not confident writing it in VB.NET as I'm a C# dev. Furthermore, it makes your code more efficient but it might not be _faster_. It could actually be slower if you're writing to a mechanical drive.

Comment: To clarify: if neither of these methods are fast enough, there's little you can do to make it faster short of upgrading your hardware.

Comment: @Llama I'm writing on the SSD, my PC is fast enough, but even on it i can notice the 7sec freezing with this code, therefore it will be much slower in less productive hardware as mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done it this way but I would think that the `Stream.CopyTo` method should be the easiest method and as quick as anything.

```vb
Using inputStream As New FileStream(...),
      outputStream As New FileStream(...)
    inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream)
End Using
```

I'm not sure whether that overload will read all the data in one go or use a default buffer size. If it's the former or you want to specify a buffer size other than the default, there's an overload for that:

```vb
inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream, bufferSize)
```

You can experiment with different buffer sizes to see whether it makes a difference to performance. Smaller is better for memory usage but I would expect bigger to be faster, at least up to a point.

Note that the `CopyTo` method requires at least .NET Framework 4.0. If you're executing this code on the UI thread, you might like to call `CopyToAsync` instead, to avoid freezing the UI. The same two overloads are available, plus a third that accepts a `CancellationToken`. I'm not going to teach you how to use `Async`/`Await` here, so research that yourself if you want to go that way. Note that `CopyToAsync` requires at least .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: `CopyTo()` is a while loop: `while ((read = Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)`, where `buffer.Length` - if not specified - is the default buffer size of 81920 bytes. `CopyToAsync()` is the same thing, except it uses `ReadAsync()` + `WriteAsync()`.